# MutableList<Int?> and mutableList<Int>

Tags: kotlin

I have a homework question:

Write the code that compiles fine but throws an exception after you assign a value of type MutableList< Int? > into a variable of type "MutableList < Int >".

That's how I see it:
On cast(get)  throws null and this can work with MutableList If we change < Int? > to < Int > we have null exception. I can't understand this task. InteliJ IDEA stops running this compilation every time .

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/

Comment: `?` safe access operator let you access a property if it is **NOT** null, if you remove it, then any operation on a null property will result in a null pointer exception

Comment: MutableList<Int?> can hold all null values for Int, whereas MutableList<Int> won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `as` operator will let you do that :

```
var a : MutableList<Int?> = mutableListOf(5, null, 7)
var b : MutableList<Int> = a as MutableList<Int>
```

Your IDE should raise an "Unchecked cast" warning but let you compile, and executing the program will raise a typeCast exception such as the following :

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.Int
```

Comment: This solution I tried before write the question..

If I change MutableList<Int?> on MutableList<Int> i just have: 

Error:(5, 32) Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is MutableList<Int?> but MutableList<Int> was expected

But i need exception (Null Pointer Exception).

Comment: I'm wondering if you haven't just misunderstood the question. The exact code I've wrote 1) compiles fine and 2) throws an exception at line 2, which is where it tries to assign a value of type MutableList< Int? > into a variable of type "MutableList < Int >". Reading your homework description it seems to me this is exactly what is expected of you.

Comment: Thank you. You really helped me. More than 10 hours i spended on this task =/ ...

Comment: The good thing is that you had it right a long time ago, you just didn't realize it ;) Cheers mate, good luck for your studies !